CSS selector using :first-of-type not working
I have this very simple example that should highlight the text red but it doesn't work. However the same exact thing with :last-of-type correctly highlights the last row red. I am not sure why the first-of-type selector is not working unless I make it the first child of parentTwo.


 .parentOne .parentTwo .thirdNested:first-of-type {
  color:red
}

 .parentOne .parentTwo .thirdNested:last-of-type {
  color:blue
}
<div class="parentOne">

  <div class="parentTwo">
        <div class="firstNested">
            <span>Some text here</span>
       </div>
        <div class="secondNested">
            <span>Some text here</span>
        </div>
        <div class="thirdNested">
            <span>This should be red with :first-of-type</span>
       </div>
        <div class="thirdNested">
            <span>This should be blue with :last-of-type</span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>




*-of-type refers to tag name so it is not affected by class name. In your case the .thirdNested:first-of-type need to match, at the same time, having the class thirdNested and being the first element (among its siblings) of the specific tag name.

You could use *:nth-child(1 of .thirdNested) for the first one and *:nth-last-child(1 of .thirdNested) for the last one.
